# Letting f be an arithmetic function, show that if F is multiplicative, then f is multiplicative.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

I'm completely stuck on this question and don't know how to do it at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $f*g=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g(n/d)$ is the convolution of two arithmetic functions, we can show that if $h=f*g$ and two of these functions are multiplicative, then all three are multiplicative.

**Lemma 1:** Define $\mathcal{D}_x$ for $x\in\mathbf{Z}^{+}$ as $\mathcal{D}_x=\{d\in\mathbf{Z}^+:d|x\}$. Then for $\gcd(m,n)=1$ the function $\psi:(d_m,d_n)\mapsto d_md_n$ is a bijection from $\mathcal{D}_{m}\times\mathcal{D}_{n}\mapsto\mathcal{D}_{mn}$.

*Proof:* Indeed for $d_m|m$ and $d_n|n$ we have $\psi(\mathcal{D}_m\times \mathcal{D}_n)\subseteq \mathcal{D}_{mn}$. Moreover, for each $d|mn$ there exist unique $d_m$ and $d_n$ such that $d_m|m, d_n|n, d_md_n=d$. Hence $\psi$ is bijective, as desired.

**Proposition 1:** If $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative, then so is $f*g$.

*Proof:* Due to Lemma 1 $$\sum_{\stackrel{d_m|m}{d_n|n}}f_1(d_m)f_2(d_n)=\sum_{d_m|m}f_1(d_m)\sum_{d_n|n}f_2(d_n),$$ for any functions $f_1,f_2:\mathbf{Z}^{+}\mapsto\mathbf{C}$. Let the domains of $f_1$ and $f_2$ be $\mathcal{D}_m$ and $\mathcal{D}_n$ respectively, and define \begin{align*}f_1(d_m)&= f(d_m)g\left(\frac m{d_m}\right)\\ f_2(d_n)&= f(d_n)g\left(\frac n{d_n}\right).\end{align*} Then we have $$\sum_{d_m|m}f(d_m)g\left(\frac{m}{d_m}\right)\cdot\sum_{d_n|n}f(d_n)g\left(\frac{n}{d_n}\right)=\sum_{\stackrel{d_m|m}{d_n|n}}f(d_m)g\left(\frac{m}{d_m}\right)f(d_n)g\left(\frac{n}{d_n}\right).$$ We have $\gcd(x,y)=1$ for all $x\in \mathcal{D}_m$ and $y\in \mathcal{D}_n$, so we get $$\sum_{\stackrel{d_m|m}{d_n|n}}f(d_m)g\left(\frac{m}{d_m}\right)f(d_n)g\left(\frac{n}{d_n}\right) = \sum_{\stackrel{d_m|m}{d_n|n}}f(d_md_n)g\left(\frac{mn}{d_md_n}\right)=\sum_{d|mn}f(d)g\left(\frac{mn}{d}\right),$$ as desired. $\Box$

**Proposition 2:** If $f*g$ is multiplicative and one of $f$ or $g$ is multiplicative, then so is the other.

*Proof:* Suppose $g$ is multiplicative. We want to show that $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for all coprime $m,n\in\mathbf{Z}^+$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction there exists a nonempty set $\mathcal{S}$ such that $$\mathcal{S}=\left\{k\in\mathbf{Z}^+:k=mn, mn\in\mathbf{Z}^+, \gcd(m,n)=1\,\mid\, f(mn)\neq f(m)f(n)\right\}.$$ By the Well-Ordering principle, there exists a minimal element of $\mathcal{S}$, say $k+1$. Consider $m,n\in\mathbf{Z}^+$ such that $mn=k+1$. We have $$(f*g)(mn)=\sum_{d|mn}f(d)g\left(\frac{mn}{d}\right) = f(mn)+\sum_{\stackrel{d|mn}{d<mn}}f(d)g\left(\frac{mn}{d}\right).$$ Let $d=rs$ for $r|m, s|n$. Then $$(f*g)(mn)=f(mn)+\sum_{\stackrel{r|m,s|n}{rs<mn}}f(rs)g\left(\frac{mn}{rs}\right)=f(mn)+\sum_{\stackrel{r|m,s|n}{rs<mn}}f(r)g\left(\frac{m}{r}\right)f(s)g\left(\frac{n}{s}\right),$$ by the minimality assumption. We can rewrite the sum as \begin{align*}(f*g)(mn)&=f(mn)+\left(\sum_{r|m}f(r)g\left(\frac{m}{r}\right)\cdot\sum_{s|n}f(s)g\left(\frac{n}{s}\right)\right)-f(m)f(n)\\ &=f(mn)+(f*g)(mn)-f(m)f(n) \end{align*} and it follows that $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$, so we must have $k+1\in\mathcal{S}$, contradiction. Thus $\mathcal{S}=\emptyset$. A base case is easy to verify when $mn=1$ ($g(1)=1$ and $(f*g)(1)=1$, but $(f*g)(1)=f(1)g(1)\implies f(1)=1$). $\Box$

My original statement now follows.

The OP's question that deals with $F=f*\mathbf{1}$ now follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If $n_1, n_2$ are relatively prime, the divisors of $n_1n_2$ can be written in a unique way as $d_1d_2$, where $d_1$ is a divisor of $n_1$ and $d_2$ is a divisor of $n_2$. Moreover, $d_1$ and $d_2$ are then relatively prime. Therefore

$$\sum_{d\mid n_1n_2} f(d) = \sum_{d_1 \mid n_1}\sum_{d_2 \mid n_2} f(d_1d_2) = \sum_{d_1 \mid n_1}\sum_{d_2 \mid n_2} f(d_1)f(d_2) = \left(\sum_{d_1 \mid n_1}f(d_1)\right)\left(\sum_{d_2 \mid n_2}f(d_2)\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would show it.  Let $\gcd(m,n)=1$  and consider the sets $A=\{d:d|mn\}$ and $B=\{de:d|m,e|n\}$.  First show that $A=B$.  Here you will need to rely heavily on the fact that $(m,n)=1$.  Then notice that $$F(mn)=\sum_{d|mn}f(d)=\sum_{i\in A}f(i)=\sum_{i\in B}f(i)$$  and show that $$\sum_{i\in B}f(i)=\sum_{d|m}\left(\sum_{e|n}f(de)\right).$$  Now use the fact that $(d,e)=1$ (why?) to rewrite the above sum as $$\sum_{d|m}\left(\sum_{e|n}f(d)f(e)\right) = \sum_{d|m}\left(f(d)\left(\sum_{e|n}f(e)\right)\right)=\left(\sum_{e|n}f(e)\right)\left(\sum_{d|m}f(d)\right)=F(m)F(n).$$
The above steps are made by applying the distributive law.